# In what comic does Prof X say, "If we do that we'll be no better than Hitler, Stalin, or Doctor Doom"?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, x-men, secret-wars-1985

It's from a scene in a comic from the late 70s to mid-80s. Probably from *Secret Wars (1985)*, but I may be wrong. A few heroes are talking, and a difficult choice is being debated. Professor X says, "If we did that, we'd be no better than Hitler, Stalin, or Doctor Doom."

Crossposted at [TVTropes YKTS](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/query.php?parent_id=55174&type=ykts).

Comment: And assuming I'm right, go self-post an answer on TVTropes

Comment: Thou rightly assumeth thou art right. ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're referring to the scene below from [**Secret Wars Vol. 1 #4**](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_(UK)_Vol_1_4) (from 1985) in which Xavier is describing his earlier decision to use his psychic powers to wipe Spider Man's memory.

> *In that moment of weakness I was no better than Doom ... or **Hitler**
>   ... or anyone else who ever used power to usurp another's freedom!*

[image]

Comment: Either my memory or the Brazilian translator inserted Stalin in there. :-P